# Scale div vertically until all content is shown?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

I have a div with a set height of 200, and sometimes there's enough content inside to have to scroll. Is there any way to be able to scale/grow the div until there's no overflow in Scriptaculous?

Edit: I looked at the wiki, especially at Effect.Scale (which seems like the one I want) but I couldn't find a way to do what I'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS?

```
/*In non-IE css:*/
.myclass {
min-height: 270px;
}

/*In css for IE:*/
.myclass {
height: expression(this.scrollHeight < 270? "270px" : "auto" );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized I could just use min-height and max-height shortly after posting. Thanks.